# Get final values from a specific dimension/axis of an arbitrarily dimensioned PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I had a PyTorch tensor such as:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn([3, 4, 5])
```

and I wanted to get a new tensor, with the same number of dimensions, containing everything from the final value of dimension 1. I could just do:

```
x[:, -1:, :]
```

However, if `x` had an arbitrary number of dimensions, and I wanted to get the final values from a specific dimension, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`index_select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html):

```
torch.index_select(x, dim=dim, index=torch.tensor(x.size(dim) - 1))
```

The output tensor would contain the same number of dimensions as the input. You can use `squeeze` on the `dim` to get rid of the extra dimension:

```
torch.index_select(x, dim=dim, index=torch.tensor(x.size(dim) - 1)).squeeze(dim=dim)
```

*Note:* While `select` returns a *view* of the input tensor, `index_select` returns a new tensor.

**Example:**

```
In [1]: dim = 1

In [2]: x = torch.randn([3, 4, 5])

In [3]: torch.index_select(x, dim=1, index=torch.tensor(x.size(1) - 1)).shape
Out[3]: torch.Size([3, 1, 5])

In [4]: torch.index_select(x, dim=1, index=torch.tensor(x.size(1) - 1)).squeeze(dim=dim).shape
Out[4]: torch.Size([3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`select`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.select.html) function (or equivalent [method](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.select.html#torch.select) of a tensor), e.g.,

```
dim = 1  # the dimension from which to extract the final values

y = x.select(dim, -1).unsqueeze(dim)
```

where `unsqueeze` has been used to keep the same number of dimensions as the original tensor.